# Increase Deployed Program Account Allocation

Tags: deploy, build-bpf, redeploy

I have deployed a program which got allocated `41216` bytes for the program account. I have changed this program, and would like to redeploy. However, the changed program is `46984` bytes.

```
Error: Deploying program failed: Error processing Instruction 0: account data too small for instruction
```

Is there a way to increase the existing account size (retain program id)? Or, would I need to deploy as a new program (new program id)?

I am aware of [Account_info::AccountInfo::realloc](https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/solana_program/account_info/struct.AccountInfo.html#method.realloc). However, as the program is already deployed, I would not be able to retroactively add this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible, but the code change has been done for the `ExtendProgram` instruction, and it is making its way through the enabling process: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/26385

There's also some tooling required to finish the work, so you'll likely have to wait at least a month before it's available on mainnet.

Comment: Thank you for the resource. I am wanting clarification though:
1) This appears to increase the program data size (program state), not the program itself?
  - Specifically, it sounds like it solves an issue of needing to increase data storage, but not solve the issue of re-deploying a larger binary to the program address.
2) Why does the program account not pay for the tx? If I read the code right, the program data account will pay (unless the optional account is provided).

I might just have a misunderstanding of program vs program data.

Comment: 1) Program data = program executable binary data, so it solves your exact problem. 2) The program account belongs to the loader, so it cannot be used to pay for the transaction.  It may not have enough SOL to cover rent-exemption for its new size, so the `ExtendProgramData` instruction optionally allows for a payer to transfer the additional required SOL into the program data account.

Answer (score 4):

Now possible!

Using Solana CLI (>1.18) you can do:

`$ solana program extend <PROGRAM_ID> <MORE_BYTES>`

To allocate more bytes, then try again.